# Find a route between two Wikipedia articles

Tags: code-golf

## Introduction

Recently, I was skyping with a bunch of friends and we got bored and had nothing to do, so we "invented" a "game" (some people in the comments pointed out that this game is playable online and very popular, so we definetely didn't invent it, although I hadn't seen it before). The reason I put the word "game" in quotation marks is because it's not an actual computer game, but it's played on Wikipedia.

It's really easy to play: Someone chooses some Wikipedia article as the goal. Let's assume *[Code Golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)* for this example. All the players then have to start from a random article (by pressing *Random Article* in the sidebar or going to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random) URL) and have to get to the "goal" as quick as possible using **only linked articles of the article you are currently at**. Rules include:

- The search function is not allowed (obviously)
- You may only click links in the article's main text (specifically all text inside `<div id="bodyContent">`)
- If your random page or any other page you encounter has no valid links (dead links, loops, etc) or no links at all you may roll again.

## The challenge

Here's where you come in: unfortunately I'm pretty bad at this game, but I'm also a dirty cheater. So I want you to implement this bot for me. I'm also a programmer, so naturally my hard disk is full of stuff like code, libraries and such and I only have   a few bytes of memory to spare. Therefore this challenge is Code Golf, the answer with the least **bytes** wins.

### Implementation Details:

- Of course you don't have to implement an intelligent bot that knows connections between topics and automatically detects the optimal route. Brute forcing is more than enough for the purpose of this challenge
- In the actual game, time counts. Your program shouldn't take longer than 1 hour to find the article (this is to avoid loopholes like random searchers that will "eventually" find the goal)
- If no path to the goal can be found (e.g. dead links or a loop) you can choose what to do from the list below:

  - Quit (score remains the same)
  - Get another random article and try again and do nothing on loops (score -= 10)
  - Get another random article on a dead link or a loop (detect loops automatically) (score -= 50)
  - (By "score" I mean your byte count here)
- Another 20 bonus bytes will be subtracted if you "trace" the route, so you print the title of every individual page you visit.
- Standard network libraries may be used (to avoid loopholes like "I crafted my own network library which crawls wikipedia articles")

  - The only thing network-related your program should do is send a HTTP request to download a wikipedia page
- If your program finds the page, it should quit, but somehow signalize that it finished (printing the character "f" or the title of the page is enough)
- Standard loopholes are to be avoided

**Have fun golfing!**

*(This is my first question here, so please point out obvious loopholes and caveats in the comments before exploiting them - thanks :D)*

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unfortunately (in my experience) people prefer exploiting loopholes instead of pointing them out, even if you ask them nicely not to. If you want some feedback before posting your challenge on main, you can post it in the sandbox (see Featured on Meta in the sidebar).

Comment: For a fun way to play this online with other people: http://thewikigame.com/ :)

Comment: Interesting enough for a challenge, but not enough reason for me to flood a site with requests.

Comment: Thanks @m.buettner, I'll remember that when posting the next time.

Comment: @Doorknob lol, this game is obviously much more popular than I imagined ;)

Comment: @manatwork I'm fairly certain Wikipedia has sufficient bandwith to handle "attacks" like this

Comment: Not exactly a loophole but I would look out for people complaining that this is just a graph search question that doesn't bring many new ideas to the table. I however think its fine, this site needs more questions. (Though you definitely didn't invent this "game" :P.)

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Well it adds a little spice by bringing in the network factor and such in my opinion. I'm glad you like it though. Yeah, I definitely didn't invent it :D I added an annotation about that in the text.

Comment: @HackerCow Your question is quite interesting, you should post your questions in the sandbox before.

Comment: @HackerCow I like this question, just a few little things. You described what to do if you cant find the page. But what will happen if you reach the page? and should there be output displaying what pages were visited to achieve the destination page?

Comment: @TeunPronk When the page is reached, the program should quit, but somehow signal that it's done (e.g. printing a message). By score I mean the character count. So the actual character count gets reduced by the corresponding number. Good point with the output, I'll add a few things to the implementation details I guess ;)

Comment: This is basically http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18665/194 + http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26031/194

Comment: This could have been good as a koth challenge taking the average number of hops out of 50 runs with each bot. Would give more incentive to build a more intelligent bot.

Comment: Why is brute forcing okay but the script needs to do this in under an hour? Seems contradictory. Brute forcing will, almost by definition, cause the script to take a while, especially when we're looking for one Wikipedia article out of millions.

Comment: @eric_lagergren - on the contrary I'd expect that most articles would be resolved within a few page jumps - even brute force this could be as little as a few seconds to minutes.

Comment: @NPSF3000 I suppose. I mean, I *could* open like 30 threads and try each until one finds the correct url, but that seems like an easy way to get banned from Wikipedia for hammering their servers...

Comment: @eric_lagergren to be fair the OP should have created a duplicate of wikipedia (the data is freely available) and hosted it themselves.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Mhmm. The issue I'm currently running into is that finding a page like /wiki/United_states is millions of times easier than /wiki/Code_golf, simply because the former is referenced much more than the latter.

Comment: @eric_langergren That's easy 'USA -> Personal Computer -> Application Software -> Web Application -> Perl -> Code Golf'  Now, as you state linking from a random page to USA is going to be pretty easy in most cases.

Comment: @eric_lagergren like I wrote, I mainly set this rule to avoid trolls. It's not really that much of a hard limit (2 or 3 hours are okay too), it's just to make sure someone doesn't write a program that takes tens of thousands of years to finish.

Comment: @HackerCow ahhh gotcha.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Python 373 -> 303

It reads the Wikipedia destination from `input()` (user input) and should be in the format of `/wiki/dest`. So, something like `/wiki/Code_golf` or `/wiki/United_States`. It also uses one space for the indents and `http://enwp.org` instead of Wikipedia's full URL to save bytes.

- -50 because if it finds a broken [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) it gets a new random URL.
- -20 because it prints the title of each URL visited (could change title -> URL, but title is cleaner and actually makes my source larger).

It hangs every once and a while, and I can't figure out why. Perhaps because of Wikipedia rate limits?

I found the [Boston Red Sox Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Red_Sox) in 9 minutes 20 seconds, and the United States page in under 10 seconds, so it shouldn't take *too* long to find Code Golf...

```python
from mechanize import*;from lxml.html import*;from random import*;a=Browser();a.set_handle_robots(0);i='http://enwp.org/Special:Random';t=input();d={};k=a.open
def f(o):
 if o!=i:d[o]=o
 if o in d:f(i)
 try:v=fromstring(k(o).read()).xpath('//div[@id="content"]//a/@href')
 except:f(i)
 print a.title()
 if t in v:k(t);print 'f';exit()
 else:f(choice(v)) if v else f(i)
f(i)
```

Comment: I don't know a lot of python, but this looks nice

Comment: Does it detect loops though? If it doesn't, that's 10 bonus points instead of 50

Comment: @HackerCow yeah it won't visit the same url twice except for the `/wiki/Special:Random` url. Consequently, after visiting many urls it'll eat up your entire RAM.

Comment: I'll just say this: `from ... import*`.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but are you even using mechanize?

Comment: `if t in v:a.open(t);print'f';exit()`

Comment: @TheRare oh yeah I had that but when I did that my script kept doing weird things like hanging a Lot more often so I abandoned t :/ it was very strange -- I'll try it again though

Comment: It should have no effect on the performance, so I guess you just were unlucky.

Comment: @DevanLoper oh shoot, misread your comment. Yes, I am. Originally I was using `import mechanize as m` and the assigning `m.Browser()` to `a` so when I call `a.open()` I'm in effect calling `mechanize.Browser().open()` now I'm just importing all of `mechanize` and get to skip the `... as m` part.

Comment: @TheRare you're probably right. there's no real reason for it to affect my script like you said.  thanks! I'll edit my post tomorrow when I'm not replying from my phone

Comment: You can also use 1 space indents. Oh, `else:f(choice(v))if v else f(i)`. And if I'm not mistaken, `except:v=l(a.open(i).read()).xpath(r)` -> `except:f(i)`